# How can I override auto layout (in UICollectionView)

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have an UICollectionView and a custom UICollectionViewCell containing subviews.
I am doing some "esoteric" stuff inside this CollectionViewCell and would like do rearrange
all subviews by using setFrame manually. How can I override all autolayout behaviour?

I tried to override "-(void) layoutSubviews" and draw rect. Sometimes this works, sometimes not.

If I get a cell by using

```
UIMyCell *cell = (UIMyCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"UIMyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I get my custom cell. I can assign custom properties and everything is fine. But the frame of this cell is initially (0, 0, 0, 0).

Some time later the layout will be set. I would like to be "notified" if the subsystem is setting the size.

Then I would like to set all subviews frames WITHOUT autolayout.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
On OS X (NSView)

```
 -(void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

will be called after all constraints have been updated to set new view positions and sizes.
On iOS (UIView)

```
-(void) setCenter:(CGPoint)center
and
-(void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
```

will be called instead. So overwriting setFrame is not working for iOS framework.